# Navbar hiding a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar is hiding my the div that should be above it

Not complete replica of my own but here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evans96/btojx5h7/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Burger Corner</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
<!--                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Burger Corner</a>-->
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="90" height="60">
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-nav">
                    <li class="hidden"><a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll color_animation" href="#intro">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll color_animation" href="#services">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll color_animation" href="#reservation">Reservation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll color_animation" href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a id="login_lnk"class="page-scroll color_animation" href="#login" data-toggle="modal" >Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Intro Section -->
    <section class="top-title">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Burger Corner</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Welcome section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <div id="wall_1" class="image"></div>
    <section id="about" class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>About Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS for the problematic div and the one that works :

```
.top_title{
    font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
/*    background-image: url(../images/intro.jpg) no-repeat center center;*/
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#990000;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.intro-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

CSS for the navbar:

```
.color_animation {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px !important;
    color: white !important;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.color_animation:hover{
    color: #990000 !important;
}    

.main-nav a {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px 0;
        transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav {
        padding: 0;
       /*margin:  auto 0 auto;*/ 
}    

    li{
    color: white !important;
    word-spacing: 5px !important;
}
```

Extra CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

I even tried using the `intro-section`  class and modified it, changed its name and added some code but it genuinely doesnt work.The `navbar` hides it, it doesnt have the background i told it to have or even the `height`

I made the `navbar` invisible just for the testing and as you can see the div is under the `navbar` and the orange section is the one i said i took its `css` and modified it.

[image]

Comment: Please post more relevant code(`CSS`). We won't be able to figure out the problem from this code only. Or even better try and make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oh i am sorry i will get to it right now!

Comment: @lonut i added some more CSS

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Remove the `navbar-fixed-top` class from the `nav` element. Also, the css you posted still not exemplifying the problem. Please make http://jsfiddle.net with the whole code to look like in the image you posted.

Comment: After i removed the navbar-fixed-top it worked but the navbar is no more fixed and thats somthing important, i will get to makingthe jsfiddle now

Comment: there is the fiddle, even tho i didnt manage to replicate it 100% i think the important parts are there! https://jsfiddle.net/evans96/btojx5h7/

Comment: There's no CSS solution for this. I will answer this question with a jQuery/Javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a `CSS` solution to your code. You can check the scroll position to make the navbar fixed and back to static, by removing or adding the `navbar-fixed-top` class, like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
     $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
   }
   if ($(window).scrollTop() < 51) {
     $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
   }
 });
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/btojx5h7/1/)**.

Comment: I found out that i wrote the css title_top instead of title-top but there is another problem now,  the background-image code doesnt work at all and the text goes to the orange part meaning that it goes to the div above??
 uptaded the fiddle